# Intent can't pass value correct when I invoke Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI?

Tags: android

I think  the value of `int index=data.getIntExtra("recordindex", 0)` should be 60, but I get the value 0, why?

What error do I make? Thanks!

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.sms_tel_number);

         Button btnadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
         btnadd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {               

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                    i.putExtra("recordindex", 60);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 50);
                }
        });
    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 50:
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              if (data == null) {
                  return;
              }

              //------------------------------------------------             
              ContentResolver reContentResolverol = getContentResolver();
              Uri contactData = data.getData();

              int index=data.getIntExtra("recordindex", 0); //The value should be 60, but it's 0, why

                          Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null,   null);            
                          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    String username = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    Cursor phone = reContentResolverol.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                    if (phone.moveToFirst()) {
                        String usernumber = phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), index + " B " + usernumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
             }             
             //------------------------------------------------
          }
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: system returning new Intent instead intent which you are passing in `startActivityForResult` you are getting default value 0 instead of 60.

Comment: Thanks! but how can I get the value of "recordindex" ?

Comment: you can use `SharedPreferences` for storing values on Button click and get back inside onActivityResult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you created an `Intent i` for `ACTION_PICK`, in which you are passing an extra value "recordindex". Of course you can pass value using Intents.
But the Intent you are receiving inside `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` is not your Intent. It's a different one and does not contain that extra field.

Looking in to your code, since you need "recordindex" inside same activity and does not maintain persistence, simply use it as a variable.

```
int recordindex=0;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.sms_tel_number);

     Button btnadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
     btnadd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               

                recordindex=60;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, 50);
            }
    });
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 50:
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          if (data == null) {
              return;
          }

          //------------------------------------------------             
          ContentResolver reContentResolverol = getContentResolver();
          Uri contactData = data.getData();

          int index=recordindex; //Here it is
          .........
          .........
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. The code listed here is only a sample.  In fact, "recordindex" inside different activitys, so I need a use public static int recordindex=0 to do it, right?